# Restore selected tables from .bak file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-restore

Is their any possibility to restore selected tables from a .bak file using Microsoft SQL server management studio. By using query browser i am able to open back-up file in script tab and hence select required queries, is their any similar operation is available in sql server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to restore specific objects from a .bak file. You could restore the database somewhere else, then use the Import/Export utility to refresh a table's data.